# How to wire 3way combo switches to light/fan combo?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light, fans

Can someone please correct me if I'm wrong? I'm most worried about the 3way combo switches to the light/fan fixture. With the wires shown and routes run, will there be any issues once I start wiring switches to switches and switches to fixtures? Is there an issue with travelers and such? Please see pictures attached.[image][image][image]

Comment: I take it this is new wiring, no?

Comment: "3 _pole_"? You have 3-pole switches?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel correct, this is new wiring

Comment: @FreeMan I thought the term "3-pole" switches was the same as "3-way" switches. If not, then can you explain to me the difference between the two? The switches I'm using for the light/fan combo are pictured above.

Comment: @Stephen -- a switch "pole" is an individual, isolated set of contacts on a given handle.  ordinary and 3-way switches are single pole.  double pole wall switches are a thing but somewhat uncommon.  you can get 3 pole wall switches but they're really manual motor controllers :P

Comment: I take it that this is all on a single lighting circuit that enters the picture at the bottom-most switch box, right?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that's right. This is all on a single 15A lighting circuit and the power in from breaker is in bottom-most switch box for fan/light combo and exterior light.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel also, thanks for the breakdown on the whole "pole" ordeal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your cable combinations won't work

Your first problem is that your idea of using 2 14/3s for the blue and green runs would put the always-hot and neutral going to the left-hand switch box in different cables, which violates the NEC 300.3(B)/310.10(H) provisions about current being required to return via the cable it left on and generates nail-heating stray magnetic fields in your walls.

Instead, I would run a ½" ENT (smurf tube) between those two boxes, as well as for the yellow/red run between the left and right boxes, and then use individual 14AWG THHN wires to run the circuits inside them.  This fixes the aforementioned Code issue with the blue/green run, and lets both runs use sane colors, such as black, blue/blue, and orange/orange (as green is reserved for grounding) for the blue/green run and yellow/yellow and red/red for the yellow/red run instead of being limited to what NM cable provides.

The downside, though, is that plastic old work boxes don't supply factory KOs by and large, so you'll need to make your own ½" trade size (⅞" actual diameter) KOs in them, with appropriate ENT (or PVC) fittings installed.

### Beyond that: multiway fan/light control is non-trivial

With that said, we move onto the controls themselves.  While the approach you suggest will work, it does create issues down the road.  You see, single-gang fan speed control/dimmer combos generally don't support 3-way applications (the Lutron MA-LFQM is the only one that did, but it's not easy to find nowadays), nor do dual dimmer switches.  So, I'd suggest using a 3-gang for the bottom box and a 4-gang for the left box, giving each switch its own gang and thus making sophisticated control possible without the need for unusual gyrations or "smart" switches.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your feedback and helping me sort out the suspected issue I had. I have decided to simplify the plans and added a new drawing of what I plan on achieving under the light switch picture attached above. If you don't mind, let me know if anything seems wrong with what I plan to do.

Comment: I do have an additional question/concern though. The yellow power strip lights in the kitchen island require 12v dc. Is there a way to wire them to work off a 15a 120v ac toggle switch?

Comment: @Stephen -- wire the switch on the input (AC) side of the driver